# PHP and MySQL search

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've developed a system that has 18 fields. I wish can give a multiple search (check box, radio button and textbox) to my user. The main problem is how to perform search function in MySQL besides using `if` and `elseif` statement in PHP.

```
I have 6 checkbox :
    []US
    []Canada
    []Japan
    []Seoul
    []Taiwan
    []Australia

radio button for backup service:
    []yes
    []no

radio button for security service:
    []yes
    []no

radio button for recovery service:
    []yes
    []no

textbox for basic price
    [     ]
textbox for 1 year price
    [     ]
```

Comment: It seems to be that the three sets of radio buttons would be better as check/tick boxes, since they are just yes/no options. That would simplify things a bit. Then, for multiple option sections (i.e. the countries) just use an `IN` statement. Other than that, we encourage people to give things a go here before asking. Can you give this a try and edit your code into the question?

Comment: thanks for your idea, actually I give a try but the result is not what I want

Comment: In what way is it now what you want? Perhaps clarify what you _do_ want by editing your question?

Comment: I want user can search based on their needs. we can collect their needs and perform search in mysql use php code. but I don't know how to collect their values, example if the user check only canada, seoul, and check yes radio button for security. how to write the code in php?, shall we use array?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a search button in your form and on its click event transfer the values to respective PHP page using post page or on same page and then in if else statement fire the SQL query with value you want to search from database in following manner:

```
select * from table where country = '".$_GET["country"]."';
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, how if the user have multicriteria to choose country, backup service, security service, and input the basic price?

Comment: This has a SQL injection vulnerability in it - please take care to untaint user input in your answers.

Comment: for multiple option you have to add more parameters in your query after where clause using and .